# Pypy JIT gives a speed boost even if a script is run only once?

Tags: python, pypy

I have a script that loads several hundred images, resize them and then composes a bigger image

Every time is started with a different set of images:

```
python myscript.py imageFolder/
```

Running it in a virtualenv with Pypy doesn't show a noticeable speed gain (all run in ~8 seconds with mprofile, with the pypy version spending more time in PIL.resize and less in packages initialization).

It is because the JIT gives advantage only for long running processes?

If so I can convert the script to a daemon (but I fear of memory leaks).

Comment: running profiling in pypy takes a bigger toll than in CPython. Make sure you check your performance without profiling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your description it appears that `PIL.resize()` is the dominant operation. That function is written in C and not in Python. Therefore, I doubt you can expect PyPy to make much of a difference to your script.

If you're looking to speed things up, you could consider parallelizing the loading and resizing of the image across multiple cores. I don't generally recommend using threads in Python, normally suggesting the `multiprocessing` module instead. However, for this particular task multiple threads might actually be a better fit.

Comment: +1. PyPy's JIT will optimise only Python code (which is why they're reimplementing stuff originally written in C in Python).

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: as a side note to that, CPython development has opted to have all of the stdlib written in Python, even for modules that where originally written in C. Existing C implementations are loaded by default as accelerator modules, but a fully compatible Python version will always be available.

Comment: Just for the record, in general the JIT speed up single-run scripts?

Comment: @Madarco: Really hard to say in general. If the script spends most of it's time in a pure Python loop, then quite likely. If it's a linear sequence of operations, then probably not (but then again, it depends on what those operation actually are).

Comment: @Madarco Whether it's "single-run" or not makes no difference to PyPy's JIT. It speeds up Python loops and functions that are executed frequently. So a program that is run many times, but is a very small amount of processing each time probably won't trigger much speed up. But a program that is run only once but does a lot of complex processing could well see a good speed up (assuming it's actually executing any code many times, and doesn't just have lots of completely independent code executed in sequence).

Comment: Thanks @Ben, so if I understand what you are saying: if I run the same script several times, it doesn't produce a better optimized JIT bytecode. However during a single run, repeated code will be optimized.

Comment: @Madarco Yep, exactly right. Note that this means if you're calling the same python script many times from a bash script, you may well be able to get a large speed up by converting the outer bash script to a python script that imports your original script and calls its `main` function many times. This means the JIT is only warmed up once instead of many times, which could be significant even if you get no further benefit.

Answer (score 1):

For processing images, it is liklely that the bulk of processing time in your script is spent inside PIL's image processing functions.

Those are written in native code, and already are optimized at full native speed - you won't gain much of moving the Python controler parts (code saying which images to open, and such -- think 10-20 bytes for file names against at least 10000s of bytes in each image body).

If you need more speed in there, forget about trying pypy - you can try parallelization of your code through the `multiprocess` module, though, if you are using a multicore machine.